# IndProp: re_not_empty_correct

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

```
Lemma re_not_empty_correct : forall T (re : @reg_exp T),
  (exists s, s =~ re) <-> re_not_empty re = true.
Proof.
  split.
  - admit. (* I proved it myself *)
  - intros. induction re.
    + simpl in H. discriminate H.
    + exists []. apply MEmpty.
    + exists [t]. apply MChar.
    + simpl in H. rewrite -> andb_true_iff in H. destruct H as [H1 H2].
      apply IHre1 in H1. apply IHre2 in H2.
```

Here is what we've got so far:

```
1 subgoal (ID 505)

T : Type
re1, re2 : reg_exp
H1 : exists s : list T, s =~ re1
H2 : exists s : list T, s =~ re2
IHre1 : re_not_empty re1 = true -> exists s : list T, s =~ re1
IHre2 : re_not_empty re2 = true -> exists s : list T, s =~ re2
============================
exists s : list T, s =~ App re1 re2
```

Now I need either to combine H1 and H2 into `exists s : list T, s =~ App re1 re2` or destruct the goal into 2 subgoals and prove them separately using H1 and H2. But I don't know, how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of `exists` as a pair type which includes a value and its property. Just like an ordinary pair type, you can `destruct` it.

For example, `destruct H1 as [s1 H1].` at that point gives

```
s1 : list T
H1 : s1 =~ re1
```

Given this, think about how to construct an `s` in the goal that satisfies `s =~ App re1 re2`. Then use the tactic `exists (your answer).` (which will change the goal to `(your answer) =~ App re1 re2`) and fill in the rest of the proof (it should be trivial if your `s` is correct).

Comment: Yes, it will be `destruct H1. destruct H2. exists (x ++ x0).`.